# Is my reasoning for $\lim_{x \to 0+}x^{\log x} = \infty$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Find $\lim_{x \to 0+}x^{\log x}$.

$\lim_{x \to 0+}x^{\log x}=\lim_{x \to 0+}e^{\log(x^{\log x})}=\lim_{x \to 0+}e^{\log x\log x}=e^{\lim_{x \to 0+} \log x \log x}$
where the last equality follows because $e^x$ is continuous.

$\log x \log x \to \infty$ as $x \to 0+$

Therefore we can conclude $\lim_{x \to 0+}x^{\log x}=\infty$

Is this reasoning correct? These manipulations are still new to me and I want to make sure I am writing true things and justifying them correctly.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Please don't delete a question after getting answers or answer-like comments.

Comment: Everything is correct. And $e$ is not continuous, the *exponential function* is, $e$ is just a number.

Comment: OK got it. After being satisfied with responses, I will leave the question up. if you want the post to stay, it can stay.

Comment: Can we write "lim" until we have proved that such a limit exists?

Comment: It seems ok. But I always need some numerical evidence. There can be always surprises in abstract world.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen how would you recommend I first establish the existence of the limit?

Comment: Let $x_0>0$. I would start by defining $x_0^{logx_0}$. But that's just what I would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0>0. \log x_0 \in \Bbb R$. Let us recall that by definition, $$x_0^{\log x_0}=\exp (\log x_0\times \log x_0)=\exp((\log x_0)^2)$$
Then we can define $$]0,+\infty[\to \mathbb R$$
$$x\mapsto x^{\log x}$$

We know that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\log x=-\infty$. So, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\log x)^2=+\infty$.

We also know that $\lim_{y \to +\infty}\exp y=+\infty$.

So, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{\log x}$ exists and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{\log x}=+\infty.$
[image: Illustration of the graph]